# How to query time specific performance in postgres?

Tags: postgresql, statistics

The data in the pg_stat_statements table is really useful for me. I need to know the queries and the time they take. How can I perform a query to pg_stat_statements to get the "total_time" over the last 2 hours? I see no column for this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are interested in a two hour period, you can collect the aggregated data, save it with a insert statement and then call [pg_stat_statements_reset()](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/pgstatstatements.html#id-1.11.7.39.7) for refreshing the data.

```
SELECT 
  query,
  SUM(total_time) as total_sum,
  (total_time / 1000 / 60) as total_minutes, 
  (total_time/calls) as average_time
FROM pg_stat_statements 
ORDER BY 1 DESC;
```

Maybe you can also check [The Statistics Collector](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.2/static/monitoring-stats.html) to extend your data.

Comment: I think `SUM` isn't needed? `select query, total_time, ...` would be the same? — There's no `group by`.

Comment: `ERROR:  column "pg_stat_statements.query" must appear in the GROUP BY clause or be used in an aggregate function
LINE 2:   query,`

Answer (score 2):

I don't know of a canned tool to do this.  But you can easily create a table which has the same columns as `pg_stat_statements` and an extra timestamptz column, then have a scheduled task take a snapshot of `pg_stat_statements` into this table every 2 hours.  Then you can take the differences between adjacent snapshots of the same query.